# Starting of a remote device manager

Tags: redhawksdr

I am running a waveform that has devices on more than one computer. The domain manager and a device manager starts up on one GPP(1). A device manager starts up on the other GPP(2). The domain manager and the device managers are started when the GPP(s) are being boot up.

I can have a procedure for the operator, that states start GPP(2) up first, then GPP(1). But this approach is not preferable. I would like the ability to start the Device Manager on GPP(2) from GPP(1) after the domain manager has been started.

Does REDHAWK have a standard way of starting remote Device Managers?

Answer (score 1):

The DeviceManager is designed to wait for the DomainManager on startup.  So, the standard procedure is to add a script to /etc/init.d so that the remote DeviceManager will start up whenever the remote machine running it boots.

To clarify, let's elaborate using your example.  Machine 1 will run the DomainManager and DeviceManager(1)/GPP(1).  This machine could be at 192.168.1.1.  Machine 2 will run DeviceManager(2)/GPP(2).  This machine could be at 192.168.1.2.

The DomainManager will start up whenever machine 1 boots.  It will wait happily for DeviceManagers to register with it.

Machine 2's /etc/omniORB.cfg file is set to point to 192.168.1.1.  When it boots, the DeviceManger will attempt to register with the DomainManager.  One of two things will happen:

1. The DomainManager at 192.168.1.1 is already up and running.  In this case, DeviceManager(2) registers successfully and is ready to run applications.
2. The DomainManager at 192.168.1.1 is not yet running.  In this case, DeviceManager(2) will hang out and wait for the DomainManager to come up.